# Linking Oracle tables to Access 2007 File (Performance)

Tags: oracle, vba, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I'm running into a problem while linking some tables and views present on a Oracle 11g database to a Access 2007 file.

I'm using the Oracle Client (SQORA32.DLL) version 11.02.00.03.

If the view/table returns a small amount of data, there's no problem. The problem happens when the view or the table returns a "large" amount of data. I've tried to increase the buffer size on the driver (default is 64000) to see if that happens. I've also removed the "Enable query timeout" option - otherwise I would get a "Query cancelled by user" or a "ODBC - Call Failed" error.

In order to link the tables/views, I've used the "native tool" (External Data -> ODBC Database -> Link to data source by creating a linked table).

I was wondering if I could retrieve the data from the tables/views using vba. Sometimes, I (you should read "I" as "the users") may need to update data on some tables (control tables).

Please let me know your thoughts.

EDIT: Our goal with this project was to migrate from SQL Server 2005 to Oracle 11gR2. After analyzing the behaviour of the Access files regarding the SQL Server, I've concluded that the results are showing like a "cursor" - if you scroll down on the result window, it will load more.

I think that this may be the issue because, AFAIK, Oracle (driver, maybe?) pulls everything from the DB and, only then, populates MS Access.

Comment: What is a "large" amount of data?  I know our OBI server is set to only return a certain maximum number of rows.  Perhaps you are hitting that limit for your own server. If you have access to the client tools there are multiple ways to get information out, iqy files, the Go URL, and the obdc connection, but they all have pros and cons and have certain limitations.

Comment: By "large" (now it does have the quotes) I mean something like 2K++ rows. It should not be a big deal regarding Access. But, in terms of performance, it is. I have tables/views that return something in terms of 600K+ rows. I've edited my question to explain further the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long time after this so here goes the solution. MS access has a flag for the ODBC connection as "Treat Float as Numeric". This have made the trick.